# How to sort alphabetically treeset consisting of custom class objects by one of their fields

Tags: java

I have treeset of custom class, which consists of string with its name, which I want to be sorted alphabetically, and another treeset. I want to sort this class, but I have no idea how. I tried something like this, but I have no idea, what should I write in place of "???". Or maybe should it be done completely differently?

```
public class Turniej 
{
Set<Zawody>zaw = new TreeSet<Zawody>
(
new Comparator<Zawody>()
{
    public int compare(Zawody z1, Zawody z2)
    {
      ???
    }
}
)
;      
....
}

public class Zawody 
{
String nazwaZawodow;
SortedSet<Start> start = new TreeSet<Start>
...
}
```

Comment: You're on the right track.  `compare` needs to do the logic to determine whether Zawody s1 is greater, equal, or less than Zawody s2, and return an appropriate integer (negative if s1 is less, 0 if they are equal, positive if s1 is greater (I think))...  making this a comment because my Java is a bit rusty...

Comment: @TheLostMind your example is comparing two different fields on the same object...probably not what the OP is after.

Comment: @TheLostMind Additionally, that is only necessary (and only works!) for primitive numeric types. For strings (as indicated by OP), delegating to `compareTo` of the field is the correct approach (modulo `null` issues).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - Can you explain , briefly.. :)

Comment: `>` is not defined on non-numerical data. It does work for primitive wrappers, but is not the best choice because `compareTo` is more concise and more obvious. On strings you don't have a choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this

```
public int compare(Zawody s1, Zawody s2)
{
   return s1.getNazwaZawodow().compareToIgnoreCase(s1.getNazwaZawodow());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the javadoc of Comparable interface: the method returns 0, 1 ( > 0), -1 (<0) if s1 is equal, greater or lesser than s2

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compare(Zawody s1, Zawody s2)
{
  int comp = s1.getField().compareTo(s2.getField()); // String or other comparible
  if (comp == 0) {
      comp = Integer.compare(s2.getField2(), s1.getField2()); // Integer primitives
  }
  return comp;
}
```

You can keep nesting the comparisons if comp == 0 as far as you like to sort by as many fields as you like.

To compare integers just use the static method in the Integer class. You can either negate the result or put the values into the method whichever way around you like to sort either ascending or descending.

To compare `Comparable`s (Strings are `Comparable`) just use `compareTo`. To reverse the sort order just negate the result or put the sort values the other way around.

Be aware that if `getField()` ever returns null you will need logic to handle that case or a null pointer exception will be thrown.